# Como verificar se o timestamp é de hoje?

Tags: php, timestamp

Tenho um JSON obtido de uma API que retorna uma lista de eventos assim:

```
Array
(
    [alertList] => Array
        (
            [alerts] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 145392039
                            [name] => Failed Zonetransfer 
                            [type] => Failed Zonetransfer (Critical)
                            [startDate] => Aug 22, 2016 10:24 AM
                            [errorString] => 
                        )
              )
            [errorString] => 
      )
)
```

Eu uso `strtotime` no indice `startDate` para formatá-lo para timestamp.

Como posso verificar se o evento é de hoje?

Pensei em comparar com o dia atual, pegando o timestamp às 00:00, mas não deu certo:

```
$date  = new DateTime();
//$date->add(new DateInterval('PT1D')); essa linha tem erro, o parametro creio eu
$timestamp = ($date->getTimestamp()*1000);      
echo $timestamp.PHP_EOL;exit;
```

Comment: Poste um modelo do retorno.

Comment: Array
(
    [alertList] => Array
        (
            [alerts] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 145392039
                            [name] => Failed Zonetransfer 
                            [type] => Failed Zonetransfer (Critical)
                            [startDate] => Aug 22, 2016 10:24 AM
                            [errorString] => 
                        )
              )
            [errorString] => 
      )
)
Eu dou strtotime no indice startDate para formatar para timestamp

Comment: Só preciso saber, é de hoje, dia 22? o horário creio eu iniciar as 00:00

Comment: Ou precisava pegar o timestamp de hoje às 00:00 eu já estou usando isso: $date  = new DateTime();
  //$date->add(new DateInterval('PT1D')); essa linha tem erro, o parametro creio eu
                $timestamp = ($date->getTimestamp()*1000);  
  echo $timestamp.PHP_EOL;exit;
estou multiplicando por 1000 pq é em milissegundos.

Comment: Daniel por favor coloque o formato de retorno do Json e um minimo de código para sabermos o que já fez.

Answer (score 4):

Basta comparar a data formatando-a com [`date`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php):

```
if(date('d/m/y') == date('d/m/y', strtotime('Aug 22, 2016 10:24 AM'))) {
    echo "É hoje!"; // Ludmilla curtiu
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Solução:

```js
public function validAlert(array $alerts){
  $alertsValid = array();
  $today = new DateTime();  

  for($i=0; $i < count($alerts['alertList']['alerts']); $i++){
   $timestamp = strtotime($alerts['alertList']['alerts'][$i]['startDate']);
   $timestamp = date('d-m-Y', $timestamp);
   $date = new DateTime($timestamp);
   $diff = $date->diff($today);
   $interval = intval($diff->format('%a%'));
   if($interval === 0){
    array_push($alertsValid, $alerts['alertList']['alerts'][$i]);
   }  
  }//for
  return $alertsValid;
      
 }/*Final Function ValidAlert*/
```

Answer (score -1):

Eu faço assim:

```
$dt = new DateTime();
$dt2 = new DateTime();
$dataAtual =  $dt->getTimestamp();

$dt2->setTimestamp(145392039);
if($dt->format('d') == $dt2->format('d'))
{
    echo 'É hoje';
}
else
{
    echo 'Não é hoje';
}
```